# /srv/mm/Music (etc) Twonky won't scan here for media

Tags: media, arch-linux, shared-folders

Is there something special about `/srv/mm/` that Twonky server refuses to scan there?

I previously had my system set up with all my Music, Video and Photo folders in `/srv/mm` shared by Samba, miniDLNA etc, with no problems.

I came to install Twonky to replace miniDLNA and after two days of tearing my hair out, changing permissions and owners of the directories I ended up making a new directory at `/multimedia` and moved my Music, Video and Photo folders in there.  Twonky then scanned them all straight away with no problems.

I'm running Arch Linux (plugapps specifically) on a NAS.

The solution is already implemented (moving the directory) I'm just wondering technically why Twonky might have refused to look for my media in the `/srv/mm` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the /srv dir is blacklisted by Twonky from being scanned, along with some other directories specific to the system, this, usually would make sense, but when hosting a media server, the most obvious place for the media you need scanning is within the directories of the services it serves.

The obvious solutions here are to move the music data out of the /srv dir and setup twonky as such, or, keep them there and symlink else where.

I simply went the route of moving all my media to a new dir at /multimedia/ and subsequently had to update all my Samba share locations, FTP settings, web-server home dir and a few other things.